# php perfomance microtime real value

Tags: php, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this microtime showing up weird in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310045/why-is-this-microtime-showing-up-weird-in-php)

I use this code to check performance of the script.

```
$start_time = microtime(1);
// execution some code
$cpu_time = microtime(1) - $start_time;
```

the output of echo $cpu_time is something like 3.0994415283203E-6
how to display this to real value like 0.000000003099 on the screen ? Is it 0 seconds and very quick execution, right? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right :) 
Try using number_format() function:

```
echo number_format($cpu_time, 12);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format).

Like:

```
number_format($microtime, 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bcsub`

Example

```
echo  bcsub ( microtime ( 1 ), $start_time, 16 );
```